# Rails add a path from one controller to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

On a checkout controller if the user did not fill in their address he should be redirected to the address path, but after the redirect rails is outputting:

> undefined method `new_user_address_path' for #

The checkout code:

```
def checkout
  @order = current_user.cart.orders.find(params[:id])
  if current_user.address.blank?
    redirect_to new_user_address_path(current_user)
    flash[:error] = 'Antes de prosseguir por favor, preencha o seu endereço'
  end
end
```

I added a helper method but it did not worked. Why is the controller warning the path as a method?

**Routes**

*user address*

```
 user_address    POST     /users/:user_id/address(.:format)                                   address#create
 new_user_addres GET      /users/:user_id/address/new(.:format)                               address#new
```

*checkout*

```
  orders GET      /orders(.:format)                orders#index
  order  PUT      /orders/:id(.:format)            orders#update
         DELETE   /orders/:id(.:format)            orders#destroy
```

Comment: Please rewrite this question! One can't even understand what your title means. I am sure there is a work missing.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida, thank's is more clear now?

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: the "path" you refer to is nothing more than a method. The `routes.rb` file just offers a more convenient way to define automatically those routes for you, but in the end those `_path` helpers are just methods. They can be accesses outside controllers via `Rails.root.url_helpers.`

Comment: @Iceman thank's i added, checkout is a order action

Comment: @fjapow1 We need the relevant part of your `routes.rb` file. Also in the route you just showed, `new_user_addres GET`is missing an `s` to address.

Comment: Much better now, thanks!

Comment: Your routes.rb file should expose a `resources :addresses` under the `:user` namespace and you might even have to add the irregular plural `address -> addresses` in your `inflections.rb` file

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris thank's i added the routes propely

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show] do
  resources :address, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

By default the `resources` method with an `s` considers the first argument to be a plural so it will try to remove the extra `s` for generating member urls, hence the `new_user_addres` path.

In order to fix this I suggest renaming

```
resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show] do
  resources :address, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

to

```
resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show] do
  resources :addresses, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

And adding the irregular plural to your inflections

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'address', 'addresses'
end
```

Note that you will have to restart your server

Comment: thank you very much, but, after your answer i'll change address to another name. because this is too much for a simple change address action. anyway thank you very much

Comment: Address does seem like a legit name. It is common to add special plurals and Rails inflector handles this very well (it was designed for it after all). The code should bend to your will and the will of the english language not the opposite ;-)